# Website fully loads then immediately crashes in Internet Explorer

Tags: pages

The website I run www.detroitdungeon.com loads perfectly fine in every browser but in IE it crashes after loading. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to debug any issue, follow these steps:

1. Check Firefox or another browser to make sure it's not a system issue but is, in fact, a browser issue.
2. Use the build-in debugger in IE to diagnose your problems.

You've already done step 1.  You've pointed out that the site works well everywhere *but* IE.

I did step 2 for you.

---

The site loads fine in IE until you hit the page onLoad event.  Then, something fires that replaces your entire page content with the following:

```
<div id="stimuli_overlay" style="display: none;"/>
<div id="stimuli_lightbox" style="display: none;">
    ...
</div>
```

This means your lightbox plugin is malfunctioning in IE.  Try disabling it to verify (the site should start working in IE again).  If it is the lightbox plugin, you'll need to find an alternative.

Comment: Disabled the lightbox feature and it still crashes.

Comment: Now it's replacing your content with nothing at all ... the `<body>` element is empty after page load.  Disable *all* of your plugins, then turn them back on one at a time until you find the one causing the problem.

Comment: Turns out that it's actually google analytics doing it. It's outdated so maybe that's the problem. Thanks so much for all your help.